# Getting "redirected you too many times" error when using apache Shiro authorization

Tags: spring, apache, redirect, shiro

I have a Spring web application using Apache Shiro as security layer.
I'm trying to implement simple authentication and authorization.

My security context xml is:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/myApp/login" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/myApp/" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/someUnauthorizedUrl"/>

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /someUnauthorizedUrl = anon
            /myApp/** = authc, roles[user]
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Once I added the authorization, by using "roles[user]" I'm getting "redirected you too many times" in the browser.

By debugging in the browser I see indeed multiple redirections to "/login". 
It looks like a redirection loop that was created.

When I navigate directly to localhost/myApp/login I also getting the same error, despite the fact that that the login url should be automatically by Shiro.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
<property name="successUrl" value="/myApp/" />
```

to

```
<property name="successUrl" value="/myApp/home" />
```

where home is the homepage